# C++ Find Certain Element in Queue

Tags: c++, find, queue, element

The idea is fairly simple and for the task it needs to be a queue, so please dont suggest other methods.

I need to have a full queue, for example 5 elements of (5,4,3,2,1) and the user has to enter the position of the element they want to be moved to the front. E.g, Position 3, for which the element is 2. So the new queue would be: 2,5,4,3,1...

I have been working on this for a long time so it isnt like as soon as I hit a wall I ask for help. Would just like a nudge to get me working in the right direction again :) thanks

Comment: If they enter three, pop 3 elements into another data structure, pop the desired element, push the 3 elements back into the queue, and then push the desired element.

Comment: So far Peter I have tried using a temp queue but I had trouble finding the right syntax to get the position of the element in the queue selected. I used while statements to empty and fill the queues with data. And I shall try that Moo, thanks. Be back soon.

Comment: How is the element in position 3 '2'? AFAICT it should be 3.

Comment: 0 is 5, 1 is 4, 3 is 2, 2 is 3. Or do queues not work like arrays?

Comment: Queues do not work like arrays. But that's irrelevant. Indexes still work since it's human interpretation on a data visualization. We just count. I just counted differently :) I was fixating on the dilemma of whether we'd start counting at the left or at the right.

Answer (score 4):

Queue representations are pretty arbitrary. I'd use a deque:

```
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::deque<int> queue { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    auto b = begin(queue);

    std::cout << "Which element? ";
    int n;
    if (std::cin >> n && n > 0 && size_t(n) <= queue.size())
    {
        std::rotate(b, b+n-1, b+n);
        for (auto i : queue)
            std::cout << i << " ";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "invalid input\n";
    }
}
```

See it **[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa6d9ecc348c84ee)**

If by queue you mean LIFO-access only, then it'd become:

```
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::queue<int> queue, stash;
    for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i)
        queue.push(i);

    std::cout << "Which element? ";
    int n;
    if (std::cin >> n && n > 0 && size_t(n) <= queue.size())
    {
        while (--n)
            stash.push(queue.front()), queue.pop();

        if (!stash.empty())
        {
            int select = stash.front();
            stash.pop();

            while (!stash.empty())
                queue.push(stash.front()), stash.pop();

            queue.push(select);
        }

        while (!queue.empty())
        {
            std::cout << queue.front() << " ";
            queue.pop();
        }
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "invalid input\n";
    }

}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bc3ccef230124d9) too**

Comment: Your LIFO only is what I meant, but your solution above causes alot of errors around line 9. It looks like the advanced for loop.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the outdated compiler then :) As you **[can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f65e7ab3a27fd43a)** it does, in fact, not generate errors. But hold on a second: ... **FIXED**

Comment: You're a genius sir :D Great example. I'll see how I can learn from this to help my program.

Comment: It keeps coming up for me that the stash, or in my case a temp queue is empty. But I have tried to follow your format. So any ideas why this is?

Comment: It means that you want to get the element to the front that is already in front.

Comment: Ignore this comment if you read it. It does work. I just didnt see it as I hadnt got testing cout statements. But it does not yet display the results back to me... we shall soon see why

Comment: It would help if you showed code instead of <strike>whining</strike> trying very hard to describe things in prose :) Why don't you edit it right on http://coliru.com? That site is pretty patient and free.

Comment: @user3397180 review notes: rename `addToQueue` -> `readQueue` or `fillQueue`. Remove the call to `moveNthToFront` from it (because it doesn't "add to queue"). Drop the array. It's not used and it's never freed (memory leak). Don't pass the `qsize`, because the queue already knows. Consider a better name for `qCharacters`, because, why characters?). Add error handling/input validation. For dumping consider a helper: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7205627/. Use `size_t` for `qSize` because comparison would fail if `qSize<0`.

Comment: Here's a **[cleaned up version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/751035deafd16483)** in case you're interested. Note that you may want to revisit the reordering code because the result looks surprising to me, now. (Note that (a) functions have gotten smaller (b) errors are being checked (c) output is improved (d) functions don't have different responsabilities)

Answer (score 4):

you can use **deque** instead of **queue** in order to searching for a particular item in a queue easily. Here is the syntax:

```
find(myDeque.begin(), myDeque.end(), myValue);
```

Reference: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/#:~:text=std%3A%3Adeque,its%20front%20or%20its%20back[][1]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/#:%7E:text=std%3A%3Adeque,its%20front%20or%20its%20back%5B%5D%5B1%5D)